# Getting this Error While running docker-compose up - TypeError: redis.createCient({}) is not a function

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, docker-compose

I wrote this script to count the users every time they visit.
But during the build process, it's successfully downloading and installing the dependencies
but when executing using command **docker-compose up** the line redis.createClient({}) is throwing error as to its not a function.

[image: Getting Error After Executed docker-compose up command]

---

```
**#Dockerfile**
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

---

```
**#docker-compose.yml** 
version : '3'

services:
  redis-server:
    restart: always
    image: redis
  node-app:
    restart: on-failure
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4001:8081"
```

---

```
**# Application Code**

const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');
const process = require('process');

const app = express();
const client = redis.createClient({
    host: 'redis-server',
    port: 6379
});
client.set('visits', 0);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    client.get('visits', (err, visits) => {
        res.send('Number of visits ' + visits);
        client.set('visits', parseInt(visits) + 1);
    });
});

app.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 8081');
});
```

Comment: Where is the error message ? How is this installed ? Where is the `Dockerfile` ? Where is the `docker-compose.yml` ? How is this code related to `docker` ? How to you run this ?

Comment: I have added the docker-compose.yml file dockerfile and the error image above the links. I'm running this on the cent-os 7 environment. Thank you

Comment: That's a typo the error message says `redis.createCient` (**missing "l" in Client**) but in your source code in the question you wrote it correctly, the error message doesn't match the code from the question... Also don't post screenshot of code, paste it directly in the question.

Comment: ohh, I removed older images then ran it again and it resolved the issue. Thank you.